# TeamCity port 80 is already in use, I think

Tags: teamcity

I have no clue what other program might be using port 80, but after checking the TeamCity log file, it appears to be in use already:

The following is from catalina.2012-12-03.log:

SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind :80
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:382)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:553)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:369)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:937)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:781)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:573)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:598)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)

I tried changing the port when the 'Configure Build Agent Properties' window came up during installation, in the serverUrl property, but this didn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a configuration file I use to change the server port, and then maybe restart the TeamCity services?

Comment: You need to do a little more research before we can possibly help you.  For instance have you done netstat -a?  Have you looked at ps or lsof?

Comment: netstat -a revealed I'm listening on port 80.

Comment: Strange thing is, going to localhost in my web browser doesn't work (Google Chrome pops up with "Oops! This link appears to be broken")

Comment: Settings should be in <TeamCity Home>/conf/server.xml file (See  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by going into `TeamCity folder\conf\` and opening up `server.xml`.

About halfway down there was the following:

```xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="60000"
           redirectPort="8543"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```

So I changed the `port` attribute to `81` and restarted the build agent and server services and it worked!  I can now access TeamCity web at `http://localhost:81`.

Comment: You may also have to change the build-agents properties for calling the new port in `TeamCity folder\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties`